# Loop/print an associative array's keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an PHP array with some keys and values.

```
Array
(
    [Group A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Prod A
            [1] => Prod B
            [2] => Prod C
        )

    [Group B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Prod A
        )

    [Group C] => Array
        (
            [0] => Prod A
            [1] => Prod B
        )

)
```

Now I'm stuck though on how I'd best go about printing this. What I'm thinking of is something like:

**Group A**:
 - Prod A
 - Prod B
 - Prod C

**Group B**:
Prod A

**Group C**:
-Prod A
-Prod B

Basically just iterating through the array, printing one index name at a time and the items under it.

Comment: Sorry what's your question?

Comment: Two foreach loops nested into another, done.

Comment: I've been trying key and array_keys out but can't get the indexes to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
foreach ($myArray as $group => $subArray )
{

    echo $group . ": \n";
    foreach ( $subArray as $prod )
    {
         echo "\t" . $prod . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: And that did the trick. Thanks! Know where I can read more about that use of => in the foreach statement?